# adding own library in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-6

i want to include a php file .module file like this using hook_init

```
function drupsocial_init() {
  require_once base_path().(drupal_get_path('module', 'drupsocial') . '/libraries/dsinvoke.php');

}
```

but showing this error

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/drupal6/trunk/sites
/all/modules/drupsocial/libraries/dsinvoke.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs
\drupal6\trunk\sites\all\modules\drupsocial\drupsocial.module on line 32
```

how can i include such file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally can include any file if you know the full path of the file and the file is accessible. Check the path to the library, correct it and you should not have any problem.

Start with the full path to the file first. If that works, you can think about using a dynamic path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

why drupal trying to load the file in the trunk directory ? are you working on a svn repo ? i think there's something wrong with that path.

I also suggest you to check permissions

Hope this helps